# Joomla 3.1 not allowing install of plugins

Tags: joomla

I tried installing advanced custom HTML plugins on my  Joomla 3.2 based site but I keep getting the same error again and again

```
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file,error
```

The xml file does exist inside the zip file. Here are the contents of the xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<install client="site" method="upgrade" version="1.5.0" type="module">
<name>Custom HTML advanced</name>
  <author>Pluginaria.com</author>
  <creationDate>November 2013</creationDate>
  <copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 Pluginaria.com.</copyright>
  <license>GNU/GPL v2 or later http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html</license>
  <authorEmail>feedback@jtricks.com</authorEmail>
  <authorUrl>www.pluginaria.com</authorUrl>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <description> Allows to place custom HTML into module position. Unlike standard mod_custom, can modify module chrome it is displayed with (to remove boxes around the module usually imposed by some templates in certain module positions). </description> -<languages>
  <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_custom_advanced.ini</language>
</languages> -<files>
<filename module="mod_custom_advanced">mod_custom_advanced.php</filename>
</files> -<params>
<param type="textarea" cols="40" rows="32" description="" label="Custom HTML" default="" filter="raw" name="customHtml"/>
<param type="textarea" cols="40" rows="16" description="" label="Custom PHP code" default="" name="evalPhp"/>
<param type="text" description="Use 'none' (without quotes) to remove chrome imposed by template." label="Override module inclusion style (chrome) set by template" default="" name="moduleStyle"/>
<param type="spacer" default="HTML Header options" name="@spacer"/>
<param type="textarea" cols="40" rows="16" description="Will be placed inside style tag in HTML header." label="CSS style overrides" default="" name="cssOverride"/>
<param type="text" description="Style sheet (.css) file. Will be referenced in HTML header." label="CSS style sheet" default="" name="styleSheet"/>
<param type="text" description="Javascript file (.js) file. Will be referenced in HTML header." label="Javascript file" default="" name="javascriptFile"/>
</params> -<params group="advanced">
<param type="text" description="PARAMMODULECLASSSUFFIX" label="Module Class Suffix" default="" name="moduleclass_sfx"/> -<param type="list" description="Select whether to cache the content of this module" label="Caching" default="1" name="cache">
  <option value="1">Use global</option>
  <option value="0">No caching</option>
</param>
</params>
</install>
```

Here is the folder structure of the plugin if that will help [image]

Answer (score 0):

It look like your module is not compatible for Joomla 3.x the XML file is for older Joomla versions.(1.5.x)

You have to create new xml file based on Joomla 3.x version.

Download the module from this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-banner-slideshow-module) the make it that way , then it will works..

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 3.1 uses a root  element of extension instead of install in the XML manifest file.  My guess is plugin isn't for your version of Joomla.